# strange graph while plotting two columns of a DataFrame

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am relatively new to python. I am trying to plot a line using two columns of a Dataframe using .plot in Matplotlib. Here is the code I used -

```
a = testdata['x_pred']
b = testdata['y']
plt.plot(a,b)
```

The DataFrame testdata has only two columns - x_pred and y.
I was expecting a smooth line graph, however the graph I am getting seems to be connecting each point with every other point. Can't understand why.  Would appreciate any help to get a simple line graph as my output.

[Here is the plot I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PMIO.png)

Comment: I think your index is off and the line is being drawn out of order. Is that possible?

Comment: You could be right, any idea, how I could fix it.

Comment: Show your process, with test data, in a minimal but complete example. It's the only way to get good help.

Comment: You were right the line was being drawn out of order. I just sorted the values in ascending order an got the graph I wanted. Thanks for identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes due to the fact that the elements in the `x-axis` are not sorted.

Consider the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [20, 5, 10, 30]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

which results in :

[image]

instead of:

[image]

So, you just need to sort them.